# After user registered in wordpress the user should be inactive

Tags: wordpress

In registration, after user registered, they should confirm the email validation link, until they validate the email their role should be inactive and they should not able to login in to the website.

Am adding the user using wp_insert_user(), in this function there is a field name call 'role' but I don't know what should be given there. I tried "inactive" but not working. Kindly suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your new users are assigned the 'subscriber' role on registration, you should hook to the 'user activated' hook and do something like:

```
wp_update_user( array ( 'ID' => $user_id, 'role' => 'author' ) ) ;
```

In your application you should ensure the 'subscriber' is locked-down or inactive (i.e. can't do anything much) and your 'author' role has the full set of capabilities that you need your active users to have.

Comment: thanks for your reply. You are right, wp_update_user will work after the user clicked the activation link. But how to make subscriber or inactive users after registration until they click the mail activation.